# Apply class to text in td/span?

Tags: html, css

I want to apply the hyperlink class to the text under td, not with complete td.Here is my html content

```
 <td id="myClass"> Apply Class to text </td>


    #myClass {
      cursor: pointer;
     padding-right: 100px  ;
     padding-bottom: 100px;
     padding-right: 100px;
    }
```

i tried

```
 <td> <span id="myClass"> Apply Class to text </span></td>
```

but it does not work as this also gets applied to complete td area.

Comment: It seems to be working fine here: [Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8cWKQ/1/)

Comment: but if you create hyperlink to a tag

Comment: <td> <span id="myClass"><a href=""> Apply Class to text </a></span></td>

Comment: What is a hyperlink class? I think you need to show an example of your code not working on JSFiddle

Comment: because td and span height and width same so its looking as you said..

Comment: If you want check then assign padding of td

Comment: @ Dalorzo . somehow its applying hyperlink class to padding also. Is there a way i can exclude class application on padding area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think want is to change `padding` for `margin` like:

```
 #myClass {
      cursor: pointer;
    color:blue;
     margin-right: 100px  ;
     margin-bottom: 100px;
     margin-right: 100px;
    }
```

**[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8cWKQ/3/)**

Comment: margin-bottom does not have any effect ?

Comment: even in your fiddle example if i change margin-bottom, it does not show any impact

Answer (score 1):

you have to hiperlink like this

```
<td> 
        <a href="url" id="myClass">Apply Class to text</a>
</td>
```

i hope i helped you :-D

Answer (score 1):

There are some things you need to learn first.

The `id` of an element shouldn't be named as 'myClass'. Its just not right - the naming convention.

Secondly, you are only applying CSS to an element. You can specify that by making use of the `id of that element in this way:

If your html is as:

```
<td> 
    Some random text here
    <span id="linkTypeSpan"> Apply Class to text </span> Some other text here
</td>
```

You can apply any CSS to this span in the following manner:

```
#linkTypeSpan {
      cursor: pointer;
      color:blue;
}
```

There are other ways you can achieve this too (other selectors). You should read about them.

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Create a border for the span and check if it is taking up the whole td.  If it is, then your code is working perfectly.  You can adjust the margin of the span so that it creates space within the td where the cursor will not change.